# Digitised problems - Combine isolines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, digitizing, arcscan

I try to digitize a large number of topographic maps. Digitizes the contour every four meters. I use the program ArcGIS 10.3 and ArcSCAN. The problem is that it has many objects in the map outside of the contour and out of that the biggest problem is that the contours are continuous but is in many pieces. Is there a way to integrate automatically and in which way? It can be solved only by the topology? there is an automatic way to come together (Merge but only the same - meters iso lines)?

[image]

Comment: Dissolve can be used to only dissolve features with a common attribute.

Comment: I try Dissolve comand but the export it was only one record.

Comment: The lines you wish to combine, do they have a common attribute (i.e. elevation)? Or are all of them "just lines"?

Comment: Just lines, I will add the high later, when I finish the digitise

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments (nearly two years ago), once you finish digitising (which, hopefully you have by now), and add an attribute for height, the best way to do this is to use the [**dissolve**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) tool.

Set the dissolve attribute to your height field and that should be all you need. If you have multiple contours which have the same elevation, but aren't touching, you will get multipart lines. In that case, I would perform a [**multipart to singlepart**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/multipart-to-singlepart.htm) operation after you dissolve.